# flutter: when target sdk version 30 to 31 got error of requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-pendingintent

I'am using flutter version is: 1.22.6,
kotlin version is: '1.6.10'
build.gradle version is: '3.6.0'

My app removed from play store due to Request_Install_Package library was running in my app, where in my app I didn't used Request_install_package, I have made changes in the build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml and later when iam trying upload App Bundle I got an error i.e. my App need to have at least target sdk version should be 31 and I have upgraded compile sdk and android target sdk version from 30 to 31 and after that code is not running in the android 12+ versions where android 11 and below versions code is running perfectly able to generate app build.

I got Issue while running in Android 12+ versions is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10582): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(10582): Process: com.app.app1.com, PID: 10582
E/AndroidRuntime(10582): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.app.app1.com: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime(10582): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:93)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(10582):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(12995): Process: com.app.app1.com, PID: 12995
E/AndroidRuntime(12995): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.app.app1.com: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
E/AndroidRuntime(12995): Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:93)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(12995):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly
Error launching application on SM M315F.
```

[[Exception which i got when running android 12+ versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYiwe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOikN.png)

## **Here is the code for android/app/build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.6, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
def flutterSdkPath = hasProperty('flutter.sdk') ? property('flutter.sdk') : System.getenv('FLUTTER_HOME')
//sdk.dir = "C:\\Users\\-\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk"
//sdk.dir = "C:\\\\Users\\\\-\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Android\\\\sdk"


def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '2'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.5.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app.myapp.com"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

## Here is code for Android/app/src/main/Android manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.myapp.com">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <!-- Add below permission inside 'manifest' tag -->
    <!-- Add below permission inside 'application' tag -->
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:label="App">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedActivityHMS"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Intent filters and other activity configurations -->
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Intent filters and other receiver configurations -->
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Intent filters and other receiver configurations -->
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Intent filters and other receiver configurations -->
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Intent filters and other receiver configurations -->
        </receiver>


        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="true">

        </service>

        <!-- Flutter Downloader -->
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <!-- End of  Flutter Downloader -->

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

## **Here is the Code of Pubspec.yaml file**

```
name: app
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  stop_watch_timer:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  flutter_redux: ^0.6.0
  redux: ^4.0.0
  redux_thunk: ^0.3.0
  redux_logging: ^0.4.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  intl: ^0.16.1
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  open_file: ^3.0.1
  location: ^3.2.4
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.20
  html: ^0.14.0+3
  flutter_downloader: ^1.6.0
  permission_handler:
  url_launcher: ^5.4.5
  connectivity: ^0.4.8+6
  file_picker: ^1.9.0+1
  camera: ^0.5.8+2
  path_provider:
  path:
  slide_to_act:
  downloads_path_provider: ^0.1.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.3
  liquid_progress_indicator: ^0.3.2
  swipe_to: ^0.0.1+8
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
  animated_splash_screen:
  new_version:
  flutter_grid_button: ^1.1.8
  like_button:
  multi_select_flutter:
  lottie:
  animated_text_kit:
  decorated_icon:
  fl_chart:
  flutter_local_notifications:
  rxdart:
  flutter_native_timezone:
  onesignal_flutter:
  flutter_geofence:
  smart_select:
  intro_slider:
  timeline_tile:


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  image_path_ios: "assets/icons/app_icon_ios.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icons/app_icon.png"
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
    

  fonts:
    - family: CustomFonts
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/CustomFonts.ttf
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
```

Can any one help me out of this, is there any solution with out upgrading flutter version to upgrade my flutter sdk version from 30 to 31?

Comment: After creating the new project with same flutter version, adding same library versions and androidmanifest.xml , i got to know the issue, due to flutter downloader library is depricated and it doesn't allowing my app to install in the android 12+ versions.